# Managed Package - Lightning App - Navigation items locked

Tags: managed-package, lightning-experience, lightning-app-manager

I'm unable to change the navigation items on any Lightning (Managed) app, however it does work for Classic (Managed) apps.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Go to Setup > App Manager
2. Edit any Lightning (Managed) app
3. Select "Navigation Items".

Note that there is a "closed lock" icon on the right hand side, however it's possible to add and remove any item available on the left hand side.

[image]

[image]

**Question**

Is there a way to unlock it? If not, is there a simple way to clone an app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is per specs:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=dev_apps_considerations.htm&type=5

> Navigation items in a Lightning app installed from a managed package are locked. You can’t remove or reorder them. However, you can append other navigation items so that they’re accessible in the Lightning app.

You will not be able to clone or unlock I'm afraid (due to it being managed vs. unmanaged)